# Text FIle - Access forbidden through http://localhost but OK if accessed http://private-ip ( LAMP )

Tags: php, localhost

I am involved in maintaining some PHP code running on a 12.2 suse box

The system creates text file reports and is kept in a symlinked folder ( Options FollowSymLinks is enabled in httpd.conf )

When I am at the box directly and logged into the app, I can access these files with 
http private.ip.of.box/symlinked-folder/subfolder/report.txt
All ok.

But I can't access these files ( though I am at the box) with 
http local-host/symlinked-folder/subfolder/report.txt   or  with
with http: 127001/symlinked-folder/subfolder/report.txt
I get an Access Forbidden error in the browser(firefox)

Any idea what I need to do to get this working ? In Apache ? In PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Note: had to use http instead of the actual http : // and 127001 instead of the actual 127 dot 0 dot 0 dot 1.

Comment: Are you able to access non-symlinked content using localhost?

Comment: yes ... other functionality seems ok ...

Comment: is the localhost implemented as an apache vhost or is it just the http config. you can have multiple configs that bind to the same root on the same host that only differ by the name that they are accessed from. I'm wondering if you are accessing through a vhost that does not have FollowSymLinks enabled.

Comment: no vhost .... just localhost/app1 , localhost/app2

Comment: jut tried setting 0.0.0.0:80 in listen.conf, that did not work either ....

Comment: ok...lets mark this as unresolved for now :) Will report if if anything changes :)

Comment: Solved - looks like this was due to me keeping the doc root in a folder under /home. Once i switched that back to the /srv/www/htdocs folder , everything was ok. I made no other changes in the httpd.conf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - looks like this was due to me keeping the doc root in a folder under /home. Once i switched that back to the /srv/www/htdocs folder , everything was ok. I made no other changes in the httpd.conf. - App/My work  has been stable for a few weeks already